# ktor with kotlinx serialization: how to use JSON.nonstrict

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

I'm trying to initialize Ktor http client and setup json serialization. I need to allow non-strict deserialization which **JSON.nonstrict** object allows. Just can't get how to apply this setting to serializer.

```
 val client = HttpClient {
                install(JsonFeature) {
                    serializer = KotlinxSerializer()                    
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 17):

You can specify json configurations using the Json builder, which you pass into the KotlinxSerializer.

```
val client = HttpClient {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer(Json {
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })                    
    }
}
```

The exact fields for the Json builder is experimental and subject to change, so check out the [source code here.](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/master/ktor-features/ktor-serialization/jvm/src/io/ktor/serialization/JsonSupport.kt#L48)

Answer (score 14):

After Kotlin **1.4.0** released:

use this for converting string to Object:

```kotlin
val response = Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}.decodeFromString(ResponseObject.serializer(), jsonString)
```

And for your httpClient use:

```
HttpClient {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
    }
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.DEFAULT
        level = LogLevel.ALL
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! So, I am already doing this in Network Layer in for HTTP client but the first one with `decodeFromString` was really helpful as I needed this for a String conversion to model.

Answer (score 11):

Figured out - we can pass in constructor:

```
serializer = KotlinxSerializer(Json.nonstrict)
```

Comment: This is deprecated now.

Comment: form what I see they seem to change the API every 2 days

Answer (score 6):

This change very often, but with Kotlin 1.4.10 and Ktor 1.4.1 you need to pass a **kotlinx** Json (be careful because there is also a `io.ktor.client.features.json.Json`, I used an import alias to distinguish them because I needed both `import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json as KotlinJson`)

```
val client = HttpClient {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer(KotlinJson { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who use retrofit, you might want to consider using `JsonConfiguration(strictMode = false)` on the retrofit builder.

E.g:

```
// your retrofit builder
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .client(httpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(
          Json(JsonConfiguration(strictMode = false))
              .asConverterFactory(MediaType.get("application/json")
        )
)
```

Source: [issue on the kotlinx github](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/169#issuecomment-529563939)

Comment: Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}.asConverterFactory(contentType)

Answer (score 4):

With the "1.0.0RC" version, the use with retrofit is as follows.

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl(Env.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(Json{
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }.asConverterFactory(MediaType.get("application/json")))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

Answer (score 4):

For ktor 2.0+

```kotlin
        return HttpClient(CIO) {
            engine {
                maxConnectionsCount = 10
            }

            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                })
            }

            install(HttpTimeout) {
                requestTimeoutMillis = 1000L
                connectTimeoutMillis = 1000L
                socketTimeoutMillis = 1000L
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Working from Rodion Altshuler's answer above, this is what worked for me in my KMP project:

```
install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable.copy(strictMode = false))).apply {
      useDefaultTransformers = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can configure the JsonConfig for the Spring reactive Webclient:

```
val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true isLenient = true }

val strategies = ExchangeStrategies
    .builder()
    .codecs { clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer ->
        run {
            clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs()
                .kotlinSerializationJsonDecoder(KotlinSerializationJsonDecoder(json))
            clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs()
                .kotlinSerializationJsonEncoder(KotlinSerializationJsonEncoder(json))

        }
    }.build()

return WebClient
    .builder()
    .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
    .baseUrl(baseUrl!!)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for 1.4.32 I have it as follows:

```kotlin
install(JsonFeature) {
                    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
                        isLenient = true
                        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    })
                }
```